# MyViewController may not respond to setMapView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

My view controller's name is **RouteToStationViewController**, in this view controller I got a warning when I tried to compile and that caused a crash later, my relevant code is:

```
- (void)loadView {
    [self setMapView:[[[RMMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 700, 700)]autorelease]]; //this line cause warning

    [mapView2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    self.view = mapView2;

}
```

The warning I got is:

```
warning: 'RouteToStationViewController' may not respond to '-setMapView:'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong but if your synthesizing mapView2, wouldn't the appropiate set function be:

```
[self setMapView2:args];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a property for the map set up in your .h

```
property(nonamtoic, retain) id* mapView;
```

Comment: in the .h file, i have a property for it : `@property (nonatomic, retain) RMMapView *mapView2;` and in the .m i have synthesized it : `@synthesize mapView2;`